# Replace in string in imacros gives error

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, imacros

I'm trying to replace the word "BHK Plot/Land" with "Plot/Land" by using the following code

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:sLB&&TXT:* EXTRACT=HTM
SET pqr {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=TYPE:HIDDEN&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET abc {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=TYPE:HIDDEN&&TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET def {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
PROMPT "{{abc}} BHK {{def}}"
SET lmn EVAL("PROMPT {{abc}} BHK {{def}}.replace(/[BHK Plot/Land]/g,'Plot\Land');")
PROMPT {{lmn}}
```

But the code gives me error : `missing ; before statement, line: 70 (Error code: -1001)`, .the code already has ";" in it then why is it giving error?
This is the [link](http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=10-Lacs) from where I m extracting data

> PROMPT "{{abc}} BHK {{def}}" ,, gives me the output "**BHK Plot/Land**".
>   so trying to replace the word from prompt

.

Any suggestion on why is that will be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex, it has been tested in imacros and it works well:

```
SET abc "hellllllo"
set def " Plot/Land yes yes yes"
SET res EVAL("var re=new RegExp('BHK\\\\s*(?=Plot/Land)','g'); var str = '{{abc}}'+'BHK'+'{{def}}';str.replace(re,'');")
prompt {{res}}
```

output:

hellllllo Plot/Land yes yes yes

Comment: here you have explicitly taken the text "BHK Plot/Land" , but I'm get the text by using attributes and the putting them in a variable and then using PROMPT. so how do you store the value of a PROMPT in a variable and use it later

Comment: You are constracting a string using two variables {{abc}}+BHK+ {{def}} isn't it ?

Comment: Yes exactly , I'm clubbed those two variable with the word "BHK"

Comment: Using "SET !EXTRACT "{{abc}}+BHK+ {{def}}" " in the code gives the output of the prompt as " +BHK+  Plot/Land "

Comment: so, if {{abc}} ="something" and {{def}}="Plot/Land" then from the string "something BHK plot/Land" you want the output to be "something plot/land" isn't it ?

Comment: this is not how you add string in javascript with imacros

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148853/discussion-between-deepesh-and-rizwan-m-tuman).

Comment: Ufff...Finally it got workiing..wow your regex skills are quite good. Thanks a ton for your effort and time... that really saved my day!